# Why am I getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to put data in my JavaFX ScatterChart?

Tags: java, javafx

I've run into an annoying error of the JavaFX ScatterChart component. I'd like to create a chart that constantly gets more points added to it. To do so, I first create a new series, add it to the chart and then start adding points to that series.

This works fine in a LineChart. For some reason, however, I'm getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when I try to do the same with a ScatterChart.

Here's an isolated test case for the situation:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {
    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Scatter Chart");

        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 10, 1);
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 10, 1);        
        ScatterChart<Number, Number> chart = new ScatterChart<Number, Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        chart.getData().add(series);
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(4.2, 2.4));

        Scene scene  = new Scene(chart, 500, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant part of the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:208)
at javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart.updateLegend(ScatterChart.java:188)
at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$2.onChanged(XYChart.java:132)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:134)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:48)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.callObservers(ObservableListWrapper.java:97)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.add(ObservableListWrapper.java:154)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.add(ObservableListWrapper.java:144)
at Test.start(Test.java:20)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Do you know what line is giving the error?

Comment: The one saying "chart.getData().add(series);"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO it is a bug, you can file it at JavaFX Jira.
The workaround is to add series at last:

```
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(4.2, 2.4));
chart.getData().add(series);
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to create a new XYChart.Series object each time I update the chart. I update it repeatedly, so I needed to clear and add the series each time.

```
barChart.getData().clear();  // <--------------
final XYChart.Series<String,Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
for(Map.Entry<Double,Integer> entry: valuesMap.entrySet()) {
    XYChart.Data datum=new XYChart.Data(numberFormat.format(entry.getKey()),entry.getValue());
    series1.getData().add(datum);
}
barChart.getData().addAll(series1); // <----------------
```